# Jenkins job dsl - some way to do a dry run?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-job-dsl

I use the Jenkins job dsl to create my multi-branch pipeline jobs.

Is there some way I could have the seed job print out the changes it's *going* to make and wait for user input to confirm?